# Imbalanced dataset, size limitation of 60mb, email categorization

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tfidfvectorizer

I have a highly imbalanced dataset(approx - 1:100) of 1gb of raw emails, have to categorize these mails in 15 categories.

Problem that i have is that the size limit of file which will be used to train the model can not be more than 40mb.

So i want to filter out mails for each category which best represent the whole category.

For eg: for a category A, there are 100 emails in the dataset, due to size limitation i want to filter out only 10 emails which will represent the max features of all 100 emails.

I read that tfidf can be used to do this, for all the categories create a corpus of all the emails for that particular category and then try to find the emails that best represent but not sure how to do that. A code snippet will be of great help.

plus there are a lot of junk words and hash values in the dataset, should i clean all of those, even if i try its a lot to clean and manually its hard.

Answer (score 1):

TF-IDF stands for Term Frequency, Inverse Term Frequency. The idea is to find out which words are more representative based on generality and specificity.

The idea that you were proposed is not that bad and could work for a shallow approach. Here's a snippet to help you understand how to do it:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np

## Suppose Docs1 and Docs2 are the groups of e-mails. Notice that docs1 has more lines than docs2
docs1 = ['In digital imaging, a pixel, pel,[1] or picture element[2] is a physical point in a raster image, or the smallest addressable element in an all points addressable display device; so it is the smallest controllable element of a picture represented on the screen',
       'Each pixel is a sample of an original image; more samples typically provide more accurate representations of the original. The intensity of each pixel is variable. In color imaging systems, a color is typically represented by three or four component intensities such as red, green, and blue, or cyan, magenta, yellow, and black.',
        'In some contexts (such as descriptions of camera sensors), pixel refers to a single scalar element of a multi-component representation (called a photosite in the camera sensor context, although sensel is sometimes used),[3] while in yet other contexts it may refer to the set of component intensities for a spatial position.',
        'The word pixel is a portmanteau of pix (from "pictures", shortened to "pics") and el (for "element"); similar formations with \'el\' include the words voxel[4] and texel.[4]',
        'The word "pixel" was first published in 1965 by Frederic C. Billingsley of JPL, to describe the picture elements of video images from space probes to the Moon and Mars.[5] Billingsley had learned the word from Keith E. McFarland, at the Link Division of General Precision in Palo Alto, who in turn said he did not know where it originated. McFarland said simply it was "in use at the time" (circa 1963).[6]'
       ]

docs2 = ['In applied mathematics, discretization is the process of transferring continuous functions, models, variables, and equations into discrete counterparts. This process is usually carried out as a first step toward making them suitable for numerical evaluation and implementation on digital computers. Dichotomization is the special case of discretization in which the number of discrete classes is 2, which can approximate a continuous variable as a binary variable (creating a dichotomy for modeling purposes, as in binary classification).',
         'Discretization is also related to discrete mathematics, and is an important component of granular computing. In this context, discretization may also refer to modification of variable or category granularity, as when multiple discrete variables are aggregated or multiple discrete categories fused.',
         'Whenever continuous data is discretized, there is always some amount of discretization error. The goal is to reduce the amount to a level considered negligible for the modeling purposes at hand.',
         'The terms discretization and quantization often have the same denotation but not always identical connotations. (Specifically, the two terms share a semantic field.) The same is true of discretization error and quantization error.'
         ]

## We sum them up to have a universal TF-IDF dictionary, so that we can 'compare oranges to oranges'
docs3 = docs1+docs2

## Using Sklearn TfIdfVectorizer - it is easy and straight forward!
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

## Now we make the universal TF-IDF dictionary, MAKE SURE TO USE THE MERGED LIST AND fit() [not fittransform]
X = vectorizer.fit(docs3)

## Checking the array shapes after using transform (fitting them to the tf-idf dictionary)
## Notice that they are the same size but with distinct number of lines
print(X.transform(docs1).toarray().shape, X.transform(docs2).toarray().shape)
```

> (5, 221) (4, 221)

```
## Now, to "merge" them all, there are many ways to do it - here I used a simple "mean" method.
transformed_docs1 = np.mean(X.transform(docs1).toarray(), axis=0)
transformed_docs2 = np.mean(X.transform(docs1).toarray(), axis=0)
print(transformed_docs1)
print(transformed_docs2)
```

```
[0.02284796 0.02284796 0.02805426 0.06425141 0.         0.03212571
 0.         0.03061173 0.02284796 0.         0.         0.04419432
 0.08623564 0.         0.         0.         0.03806573 0.0385955
 0.04569592 0.         0.02805426 0.02805426 0.         0.04299283
...
 0.         0.02284796 0.         0.05610853 0.02284796 0.03061173
 0.         0.02060219 0.         0.02284796 0.04345487 0.04569592
 0.         0.         0.02284796 0.         0.03061173 0.02284796
 0.04345487 0.07529817 0.04345487 0.02805426 0.03061173]
```

```
## These are the final Shapes.
print(transformed_docs1.shape, transformed_docs2.shape)
```

> (221,) (221,)

About Removing junk words, TF-IDF averages rare words out (such as number, and etc) - if it is too rare, it wont matter much. But this could increase a lot the size of your input vectors, so I'd advise you to find a way to clean them. Also, consider some NLP preprocessing steps, such as lemmatization, to reduce dimensionality.

Comment: I tried using cosine similarity as well for finding out the relevant emails but not of much help. Is there some other approach for reducing the size of dataset, or if you can share some links of tutorials.

Comment: Take a look at this library: https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/under_sampling.html However, the proposed answer is an approach for your problem solution.